# Change wp-content without changing the name of the folder

Tags: htaccess, directory

This does not work

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/font/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/font/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I hope that my question will be answered

Comment: Now that your question is answered, please read and act on the following: [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the preceeding forward slashes from your rules:

Example (incorrect)

```
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Example (correct)

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
```

All rules (correct)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) wp-content/themes/themename/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) wp-content/themes/themename/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) wp-content/themes/themename/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^font/(.*) wp-content/themes/themename/font/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```